# Insert a 2 horizontal lines on a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, graph, charts, line

I am trying to insert 2 lines on a bar plot with the following code:

```
PosisEink_Liq['weights'].plot(kind='bar',color=('darkgray'))
PosisEink_Liq['TAA+1'].plot(kind='line',color=('black'),linestyle = '--')
PosisEink_Liq['TAA-1'].plot(kind='line',color=('black'),linestyle = '--')
```

Unfortunately, the 2 horizontal lines do not happear along the all graph from right to left. Do you know a remedy for this problem. If possible no plot.axhline formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50] #Size of Graph
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig, ax = plt.subplots() #For multiple subplots
```